# JFilechooser not working when applet run on the web browser

Tags: java, swing, applet, jfilechooser

JFileChooser doesnt work properly when applet runs on browser. The GUI appears, but when browse button clicked no action occurs and blank file system is displayed. When applet tested from Eclipse, outside the web page  the JFileChooser works fine. How can I get the JFileChooser to access the local files?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.SystemColor;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.print.DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Test extends javax.swing.JApplet{
JFrame frame = new JFrame();// frame
JTextField textField_path = new JTextField();// browse path
JButton btnBrowse = new JButton("Browse");
JLabel Jlabel_image1 = new JLabel(" ");
JLabel Jlabel_image2 = new JLabel(" ");
JButton btnSave = new JButton("Save");

BufferedImage img = null;
BufferedImage image1 =null;
BufferedImage capture = null;

// function to rescale the image to fit in the frame
private Image ScaledImage(BufferedImage image, int w,int h){
    BufferedImage resizeimage = new             BufferedImage(w,h,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_BGR);
    Graphics2D g2= resizeimage.createGraphics();
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    g2.drawImage(image,0,0,w,h,null);
    g2.dispose();
    return resizeimage; 
}


public Test() {

    // set the framesize
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(169, 169, 169));
    frame.setSize(900,700);//2
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);//3
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    textField_path.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
    textField_path.setBackground(new Color(245, 245, 220));

    //set the text path for browsing
    textField_path.setBounds(114, 626, 507, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);//intially set the path field empty
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_path);
    Jlabel_image1.setBackground(SystemColor.inactiveCaptionBorder);


    //set the label for original image
    Jlabel_image1.setBounds(142, 29, 429, 267);
    frame.getContentPane().add(Jlabel_image1);

    //set the label for gray image
    Jlabel_image2.setBounds(142, 345, 429, 267);
    frame.getContentPane().add(Jlabel_image2);
    btnBrowse.setFont(new Font("Cambria Math", Font.PLAIN, 13));

    //set the BROWSE button
    btnBrowse.setBounds(714, 621, 89, 30);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnBrowse);
    btnSave.setFont(new Font("Cambria Math", Font.PLAIN, 13));


    //set the save button
    btnSave.setBounds(714, 580, 89, 30);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnSave);


    // actionlistener for save button

    btnSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JFileChooser jFile = new JFileChooser();
            jFile.showSaveDialog(null);
            Path pth = jFile.getSelectedFile().toPath();
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, pth.toString());
            //Graphics2D graphics2D = image1.createGraphics();
            try { 
                ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File(pth.toString()));
            } catch (IOException ox) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                ox.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    });

    // actonlistener for browse button

    btnBrowse.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("browse button");
             JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
             int figure = chooser.showOpenDialog(chooser);
                if (figure == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();               
                    if(!file.exists()){
                        return;
                    }
                    try {
                         String filedetails[]= new String[2];
                            filedetails[0]=file.getName();
                            filedetails[1]=file.getAbsolutePath(); 
                            textField_path.setText(filedetails[1]);// display the path of the image browsed                             
                            img=ImageIO.read(file);
                            image1 =ImageIO.read(file);                 
                            for (int i = 0; i < image1.getWidth(); i++) {           
                                for (int j = 0; j < image1.getHeight(); j++) {              
                                    Color color = new Color(image1.getRGB(i,j));
                                    int red = color.getRed();
                                    int green = color.getGreen();
                                    int blue = color.getBlue();
                                    int gray = (int)(red * 0.299 + green * 0.587 + blue * 0.114);
                                    color = new Color(gray, gray, gray);
                                    int rgb = color.getRGB();
                                    image1.setRGB(i, j, rgb);
                                }                
                            }
                            //*********** display image on jframe*********
                            ImageIcon grayimage  = new ImageIcon(ScaledImage(image1, Jlabel_image1.getWidth(), Jlabel_image1.getHeight()));   
                            Jlabel_image1.setIcon(grayimage);         
                            frame.getContentPane().add(Jlabel_image1);
                            ImageIcon originalimage  = new ImageIcon(ScaledImage(img, Jlabel_image2.getWidth(), Jlabel_image2.getHeight()));    
                            Jlabel_image2.setIcon(originalimage);         
                            frame.getContentPane().add(Jlabel_image2);

                            } catch (IOException e1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });


                frame.setVisible(true);

            }
public static void main(String[] args) {
Test jb = new Test();
}
}
```

Comment: Be sure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show.  If there is no output at the default level, raise the level and try it again.  I'm guessing you'll see something like an `AccessControlException`, but I don't like guessing, so open the console and copy/paste the content.

Comment: I tried setting the java console to show content. But still not able to get the expected result. I have created a UI using Jframe. I have extended the class to applet. Now when i execute the html file on firefox i just get the initial UI. When i click browse button the file system shows empty. I even tried to sign the jar file. But no change... How can I access the local file system files from the web browser

Comment: *"I tried setting the java console to show content. But still not able to get the expected result."*  Is the code catching exceptions then ignoring them?  Note that applets are a complete PITA.  You really need to have a firm grasp of debugging apps., before attempting them.

Comment: I dont get any exception. Not able to access the files on my desktop. Is it due to some security reasons that I am not able access it ??

Comment: **Me** *"Is the code catching exceptions then ignoring them?"* **You** *"I dont get any exception."*  That doesn't answer my question.  Are there any `catch` statements in the code?  If so, what happens (what does the code do) within the `catch` block?

Comment: I have added a part of the code I am working on along with main post.  This program basically browses and displays the image and its gray scale form. I tried running this applet on the web browser using the html code:<html>
 <head>
 <title>grayimage</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <applet code = "Test.class" archieve ="test.jar" width=640 height=40>
  </applet>
 </body>
</html>             . When I try to run the java applet on web browser through  html , the dialogue box for browse opens, but no files are available for selection

Comment: Huh.. OK that code shown has only two `catch` blocks and both dump the stack trace, so if I was right about the `AccessControlException` you should be seeing output in the Java console..  Perhaps it is some restriction by the browser or OS.

Comment: I have added the html link in the exception site. Still I  get this restriction from the browser side. Is there any work around to get access to the file system ??

Comment: *"I have added the html link in the exception site."*  That won't help if it is the browser or OS that is the limiting factor, not that I am sure either is the case.  Why not raise a bug report with Oracle and see what they have to say about it?